I can't select a certain record with like %value%
I have a table with this entry



ID
Navn




2700
Aaen Agro I/S v/Niels-Christian Aaen



Where Navn has the collation Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS. But when I
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Bruger] WHERE [Navn] LIKE N'%aen%';

I get zero results. What gives, and how do I make it do what it's supposed to do? I mean I can change it to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, but that also means "Michael Brændstrup Nielsen" gets selected seemingly because "ae" gets corrected to "æ".

Background
In Danish/Norwegian, "aa" is a separate single character:

The letter ⟨å⟩ (HTML &aring;) was introduced in Norwegian in 1917, replacing ⟨aa⟩. The new letter came from the Swedish alphabet, where it has been in official use since the 16th century. Similarly, the letter ⟨å⟩ was introduced in Danish in 1948, but the final decision on its place in the alphabet was not made. The initial proposal was to place it first, before ⟨a⟩. Its place as the last letter of the alphabet, as in Norwegian, was decided in 1955. The former digraph ⟨aa⟩ still occurs in personal names, and in Danish geographical names. In Norway, geographical names tend to follow the current orthography, meaning that the letter ⟨å⟩ will be used. Family names may not follow modern orthography, and therefore retain the digraph ⟨aa⟩ where ⟨å⟩ would be used today. ⟨aa⟩ remains in use as a transliteration, if the letter is not available for technical reasons. ⟨aa⟩ is treated like ⟨å⟩ in alphabetical sorting, not like two adjacent letters ⟨a⟩, meaning that while ⟨a⟩ is the first letter of the alphabet, ⟨aa⟩ is the last.

and from the Wikipedia entry on Danish orthography:

The former digraph ⟨aa⟩ still occurs in personal names and in Danish geographical names. However, in geographical names, ⟨å⟩ is allowed as an alternative spelling: Aabenraa or Åbenrå, Aalborg or Ålborg, Aarhus or Århus. ⟨aa⟩ remains in use as a transliteration, if the letter is not available for technical reasons. ⟨aa⟩ is treated like ⟨å⟩ in alphabetical sorting, not like two adjacent ⟨a⟩, meaning that while ⟨a⟩ is the first letter of the alphabet, ⟨aa⟩ is the last.

Comparisons
So, we can't treat "aa" as if it were two "a" characters next to each other.
The Unicode rules do not consider that "Aaen" contains "aen".
In that sense, it's already doing "what it's supposed to do".
That's the point of using collations: The data sorts and compares as the (majority of) users would expect, not necessarily based on the literal strings themselves.
Note
"aa" compares equal to å if the collation is accent insensitive (AI).
"Aa" compares equal to Å if the collation is accent insensitive (AI).
"Aa" compares equal to å if the collation is both case and accent insensitive (CI_AI).
"aa" compares equal to Å if the collation is both case and accent insensitive (CI_AI).
Example
SELECT
    [Accent Insensitive (AI)] =
    IIF
    (
        N'Jørgen Søgård' COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI LIKE N'%aard%',
        N'Matched',
        N'Not Matched'
    ),
    [Accent Sensitive (AS)] =
    IIF
    (
        N'Jørgen Søgård' COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS LIKE N'%aard%',
        N'Matched',
        N'Not Matched'
    );




Accent Insensitive (AI)
Accent Sensitive (AS)




Matched
Not Matched



db<>fiddle online demo
Suggestions
Binary collation
If you want to treat "aa" as two separate characters, you may use a binary collation like Danish_Norwegian_BIN2, but that's probably not what the majority of Danish or Norwegian people would regard as correct. Sorted strings will also appear in the wrong order, being based on binary codepoints instead of linguistic considerations.
Accent insensitive
If you switch from accent sensitive to accent insensitive you could write your predicate to explicitly match "aa" or "a" using LIKE N'%[åa]en%'. Also make it case insensitive if that is what you want.
DECLARE @T AS table 
(
    s nvarchar(50) 
        -- Note, accent insensitive
        COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI 
        NOT NULL
);

INSERT @T 
    (s) 
VALUES 
    (N'Aaen Agro I/S v/Niels-Christian Aaen'),
    (N'Michael Brændstrup Nielsen');

SELECT T.s 
FROM @T AS T 
WHERE T.s LIKE N'%[åa]en%';




s




Aaen Agro I/S v/Niels-Christian Aaen



Note "Michael Brændstrup" sorts before "Aaen Agro" in this collation.
Legacy SQL collation
If you want to try a legacy collation, choose SQL_Danish_Pref_CP1_CI_AS and work with non-Unicode strings.
-- Notice non-Unicode strings used throughout
DECLARE @T AS table 
(
    s varchar(50) 
        COLLATE SQL_Danish_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
        NOT NULL
);

INSERT @T 
    (s) 
VALUES 
    ('Aaen Agro I/S v/Niels-Christian Aaen'),
    ('Michael Brændstrup Nielsen');

SELECT T.s 
FROM @T AS T
WHERE s LIKE '%aen';

SELECT T.s 
FROM @T AS T
ORDER BY T.s;




s




Aaen Agro I/S v/Niels-Christian Aaen






s




Aaen Agro I/S v/Niels-Christian Aaen


Michael Brændstrup Nielsen



Conclusions
Regarding collations in general, SQL Server respects the Unicode collation rules as provided to it by Windows. Sorting and comparison rules can be complicated, and different people can legitimately disagree on what should occur.
There also limitations around context, such as whether a string represents a person's name or a place name, or how a word is pronounced. Nevertheless, computers require consistent rules.
You may not agree with the behaviour, but it is at least consistent between the operating system and the database and based on established and agreed Unicode rules. Perhaps the rules will be changed by the Unicode Consortium at some point in the future if enough people agree with your position and bring the issue to their attention.
Meantime, you should pick the collation that best meets the expectations of your users. Given the complexities of Danish practice, there is likely no Unicode collation that behaves exactly as you would expect. This means employing manual workarounds such as the [åa] proposed above.

Well I mean I am a native Danish speaker and it doesn't make sense to me, or of my fellow Danes at the office. I would definitely want aen to pick up Aaen. It would also mean that searches for %Aa% would get me results with Å, which it doesn't. For exampe there's a Jørgen Søgård that I then should be able to get with LIKE N'%aard%'. But they won't be selected, instead a lot of people with aard in their name, like Haugaard

Furthermore if I run both your examples with Aaen Agro and %aen% I get Not Matched for both results. Which isn't what I, as a native Danish speaker would want.

@JaDa I suggest you take it up with the Unicode Consortium then and get them to change the rules to meet your expectations. Or use LIKE N'%[åa]en%' with accent insensitivity or the legacy collation. In the meantime, you asked why the behaviour is as it is and I have given you an answer. Complaining to me about it won't change anything.

Interestingly enough I recreated the table with SQL_Danish_Pref_CP1_CI_AS and re-ported the data, and now I'm back at no results with LIKE N'%aaen%' while your DECLARE @T AS table example does what I would expect :v

@JaDa Did you miss the bolded remark non-Unicode strings., and the code comment -- Notice non-Unicode strings used throughout? You have an N prefix on the LIKE string so that will perform a Unicode comparison. Try LIKE '%aaen%' instead. See the documentation for additional surprising differences between ANSI LIKE and Unicode LIKE..
